# Inserting rows using If Then

Tags: excel, vba

I need the code to insert a row above the cell which is part of the if else statement. If the value of the 5th row from the bottom is not red then one row would need to be inserted above it.
I tried writing the code but im not very good at it, any suggestions?

```
Sub Trip()

Set ws = Worksheets("WH Calc_new")
With ws
If Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("G" & .Rows.Count + 5).End(xlUp) <> "Red" Then
Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("G" & .Rows.Count + 5).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Insert
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `=!` is not a valid way to compare two values. You would want to use `<>`

Comment: Not equal is <> in VBA. Moreover, you need an End If before End Sub.

Comment: It still wont run

Comment: @z32a7ul You don't need an `End If` if you write it all on a single line

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan that is hardly a known error message

Comment: A compile error message keeps popping up

Comment: @Luuklag Correct, in that case you don't need it. But as I saw the OP had a line break. Maybe it was just because of the SO engine's wrapping. But anyway, I would write it on two (three) lines, it is quite long.

Comment: how can i get this to run

Comment: And on which line?

Comment: Line 2 on .rows.count

Comment: You need a With block if you want to refer to properties of an object like that. Or you should write the object's name before .Rows. Which objects's .Rows do you refer to?

Comment: Made the changes, now the messagebox says runtime error 1004

Comment: .Rows.Count + 5 is more than .Rows.Count, which is the last valid row index. Why do you want to add 5 to it?

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, it might be easier to store the cell in a `Range` object, instead of re-finding it every time:

```
Sub Trip()
    Dim WorkingCell As Range

    Set WorkingCell = Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("G" & .Rows.Count + 5).End(xlUp)

    If WorkingCell.Value <> "Red" Then WorkingCell.EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

Now, the [`Range.Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) command is being used fine, so any issues must be with how you are finding the cell in the first place.  And, sure enough, you say

> The fifth cell from the bottom

and you write

```
Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("G" & .Rows.Count + 5).End(xlUp)
```

So, let's break that down.  The last thing that happens is `.End(xlUp)` which, per the [`Range.End`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end) documentation, is the same as pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> - which will go up until it sees a change from "data" to "no data" (or hits the top of the sheet), which isn't quite what you want.

Well, what cell is it going up from?  You've written `Range("G" & .Rows.Count + 5)` - however, `Rows.Count` will tell you how many rows there are in the *entire sheet*.  In Excel 2007+, that's 1048576 rows.  Except, you're then adding 5, which is cell G1048581.  But, how is Excel supposed to find row 10485**81** of 10485**76**?

So, let's rework that slightly.  We want to start at the bottom of the sheet (`Range("G" & Rows.Count)`), then go up until we find data (`.End(xlUp)`), and *then* move up by another 4 rows (from the 1<sup>st</sup>-from-the-bottom to the 5<sup>th</sup>-from-the-bottom) which we can do with the [`Range.Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) property (`.Offset(-4,0)`)

Now, we shove that all together:

```
Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-4,0)
```

And put it into the Sub:

```
Sub Trip()
    Dim WorkingCell As Range

    Set WorkingCell = Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-4,0)

    If WorkingCell.Value <> "Red" Then WorkingCell.EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: != is not a valid operator

Comment: This works great, all i needed to do was add the with statement

Comment: The only problem is that i need the cells to be inserted below the workingcell, any idea how to do that

Comment: Done defined another object and set it to workincell(offset(1,0) and used that in the then condition

Comment: @KarthikApadodharanan Ah, okay - your question said "one row would need to be inserted above it".  No need to define a new object, you can just use `WorkingCell.Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert` after the `Then`